# How do I use the Hammond B3X Ipad app from my Yamaha CP73 stage piano in live performance?

Tags: midi, audio-interfaces, ipad

I want to use the https://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/hammondb3xipad/ Hammond B3X app for playing keyboards live.

My keyboard is a Yamaha CP73 Stage piano. It comes with some MIDI and USB outputs, and also the standard 1/4" Jack and XLR outputs.

I have an iPad (9th generation) on which I would run the Hammond app.

I *think* I need to use an audio interface such as the Scarlett 2i2.

- Please tell me if the below sounds accurate:

(1) I would run the Left and Right 1/4" Jack outputs from my keyboard into the audio interface.

(2) I plug an Apple Camera Adapter into my iPad. This has two connections in - a USB connection to the audio interface, and a line from a powered USB hub.

(3) I can then run two lines out from the audio interface - one could go to the PA system, another to a local feedback monitor amp.

(4) I load and run the Hammond B3X app on my iPad.

Having done all this, I am hoping that if I play the keys on my stage piano, the sound that comes out of the PA is *the Hammond organ voice from the app*, **NOT** the piano sound  configured locally on my Yamaha stage piano ? Am I right in thinking this is what would happen ?

Please help if I have missed or misunderstood something.

Comment: Hi Monkeybrain. This confuses me, don't you WANT the Hammond sound? If not, what is the point? Oh, unless you want to play BoTH the app and Yam together?

Comment: Oh I see that I've written my last paragraph very badly. Thank you for pointing out. I have rewritten. Yes, I want to hear the Hammond sound, and I want to double-check that the setup I've described will work in the way I want. But yes it would also be nice to know how to switch back to the voices on the Yamaha easily, for songs that don't suit the Hammond ?

Answer (score 0):

Almost. You've gotten most of the way there except for the bit about plugging the audio from your Yamaha CP73 into an interface. This is not necessary if you don't need to hear the internal sounds from the Yamaha. The Hammond B3X on the iPad would act as "sound module" with it's synth voices.

Monkeybrain was right to ask for clarification since you could potentially want to hear both the Yamaha and the synth voices from the apps on the iPad either together or for playing different parts.

I see you edited an gave a bit more detail about your iPad so you do still need the Scarlet or some other audio interface OR a dock with a headphone out. Audio Interface will be more suitable to stage performance however.

You will in that case connect the Scarlett to the iPad through the camera connector. You'll also want to connect your Yamaha to the iPad to send your MIDI signal. One further wrinkle is that you may also want to provide a power source to your iPad instead of relying on its internal battery during performance. Which will mean a small USB hub or some other way to get both USB from the Scarlett and Yamaha to the iPad, as well as a power cable to iPad all through camera connection kit.

Thats all the cable connections you will need though and you will be set up to explore different performance arrangement options with various apps and audio plugs from there.

Its mostly covered here except for the addition of keyboard https://producersociety.com/scarlett-2i2-ipad-iphone-tutorial/